# How to configure independent .xcconfig for every Configuration(Debug, Release) in each target on a project with CocoaPods added

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a project which supports multiple Brands (used ***targets*** to configure appicon, Launch Screen .., etc) and each targets needs multiple environments where am using ***Configuration***(Debug, Release) with schemes for every configuration.

Now to add environment variables am using .xcconfig files which am not sure how to configure for every target. The Configuration on Project level in Xcode has Cocoapods configured.

**NOTE:** While pod install, it shows warning in terminal to include pods config data into my custom config file. Any easy way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a helpful link where it explains about import config into a config.

https://betterprogramming.pub/working-with-custom-xcconfigs-and-coccoapods-6b87ead94708